# jQuery Type Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jetpack

I am assisting with a non-profit WordPress site- http://ipaintmymind.org/ and there are a couple things broken with it. Foremost, a `jQuery` error is showing in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

The source is [here](http://s.gravatar.com/js/gprofiles.js?ver=2013Augaa). But I'm not sure how that's being referenced. I thought it was the `Jetpack` module, so I disabled it but no change. I'm thinking this is related to the thumbnail `href` references of `#` in the navigation slider, but I'm not sure.

Please help!

Comment: the page is using jquery 1.4.4, `.on()` was added in version 1.7, you can use `.delegate()` if you want to continue using the same version

Comment: Please post the code here. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [delegate function](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) like:

```
$( "#yourId" ).delegate( "click", function() {
   //your code
});
```

If you want to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) then you have to add **jQuery version 1.7** or **greater**

You can use [wp_enque_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add the *latest version* of jQuery